# Rewrite htaccess file for more than one variable

Tags: php, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)$ news?url=$1
RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)$ carbrands?brand=$1
```

This works fine but now I want to add something to the last rule so that it works with one and two variables.

I tried to do this by modifying the last rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ carbrands?brand=$1&model=$2
```

So the code has to work to open just the page about the car brand but it should also work when I try to access the page of a car model of that car brand. Examples:

```
example.com/cars/bmw(.php)
example.com/cars/bmw/3-series(.php)
```

My modified rule only works for:

```
example.com/cars/bmw/3-series(.php)
```

How can I make this work for the car brand webpage too?

Comment: `^cars/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind having the "model" be blank, you can try:

```
RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+|)$ carbrands?brand=$1&model=$2 [L]
```

Or, you'll need two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ carbrands?brand=$1&model=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)$ carbrands?brand=$1 [L]
```

one for each number of params.